# Use of ifconfig tag in layout xml?

Tags: magento2, layout, default.xml

What is the use of ifconfig tag inside the block tag in a layout xml file?
What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Please follow the link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237179/magento-2-i-want-to-add-ifconfig-in-override-block-xml)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of ifconfig is for condition which is coming from system config values. The value of this will be 0 and 1(boolean). According to that value block will be rendered.
e.g.

```
<block ifconfig="custom_quickview/general/enable" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" after="product.info.addtocart" name="goto.product" as="goto.product" template="Custom_Quickview::gotoproduct.phtml"/>
```

In this case if under system config custom_quickview/general/enable == 1 then only this block will be rendered else not.

Comment: @YDF Welcome. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 6):

The `ifconfig` attribute allows you to specify a path to Magento's configuration (e.g. `dev/log/active`) that will be evaluated as a boolean value (using `Mage::getStoreConfigFlag()`). If this configuration option is set to `true` the action method will be called, **the block will be created** or the content of the reference will be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it's a condition in that block to render it or not, this condition you will set it in `Admin->Stores->Configuration->All that config boolean fields` and it comes in this format:

```
ifconfig="section/group/field"
```

[image]