# Magento 2 How to disable module using xml file?

Tags: magento2, module

I am facing issue to create module. I created one module and I given apply to system admin to enable disable.
So, Right now I am doing module hide/show using below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$module_enable = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('magefilter/magefilter/enable');
if(isset($module_enable) && $module_enable==1){
```

but is there any way if I can disable module from admin then it is disable by xml file.

I means is there any way to not ovverride that xml.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, This is just suggestion instead you think to set condition in the XML file you can create Helper and create a function that will check the module enable condition so that you can use anywhere in the project.

Comment: @PraveenChelumalla actually I override some XML file based on install-module. Once I install the module then XML is overridden. It does not depend on the admin enable/disable option. So, I want to XML depend on the admin option. is there any way?

Comment: Okay, then I also need to research this thing.

Comment: try ifconfig in your xml block

Comment: @SukumarGorai how ?

Comment: Try this -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85032/magento-2-ifconfig-in-layout-xml

Answer (score 0):

You can find your module from here 'app/etc/config.php' and replace 1 to 0 then it will be disabled. Clean cache

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, bro. But I don't want to disable the module from everywhere. I just disable for the front side. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your directory and find 'app/etc/config.php

If you want disable module just replace 1 to 0. For your check our below example.

'Developer_Categoryimages' => 1, Replace To 'Developer_Categoryimages' => 0

After that flush Magento Cache.

Comment: thanks but I do not want like that. If I Disable from admin then configuration page and then disable from the only front side. I mean no-load XML and CSS or anything in front.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your directory and find 'app/etc/config.php

If you want disable module just replace 1 to 0. For your check our below example.

'Developer_Categoryimages' => 1, Replace To 'Developer_Categoryimages' => 0

open the terminal and navigate to Magento webroot.

$ cd /var/www/html/magento2

$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade

$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

$ cd generated

$ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2/generated

$ php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

if you want to used only XML file for Enable and Disable Module. you have to Used ifconfig in Block conteiner and Refernece Container.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_desc_main_column" template="category/desc_main_column.phtml" ifconfig="config_path/group/field" before="category.products"/>

<move element="category.image" destination="content" ifconfig="config_path/group/field" before="-"/>
```

and what is ifconfig value and how it's come [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241512/use-of-ifconfig-tag-in-layout-xml)

[Reference link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85032/magento-2-ifconfig-in-layout-xml)

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

Disable module output in a simple deployment
The procedure for disabling module output on a single instance of Magento is easier because the changes don’t have to be distributed.

Archive the original <Magento_install_dir>/app/etc/config.php file.
Add the advanced and modules_disable_output sections to the config.php file (if they don’t already exist):
'system' =>
array (
'websites' =>
array (
'base' =>
array (
'advanced' =>
array (
'modules_disable_output' =>
array (
'Magento_Review' => '1',
),
),
),
),
),